# Saving Game Currency Swift 3.0 Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift3

The output that I am trying to achieve is to save the in game currency so that it's still available when the user re-opens the app. When the user collects more currency, I would like the collected currency to be added to the total currency.

With the code that I have, the currency doesn't save when the app is re-opened.

I am still learning swift so any help / advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
let totalCoinDefault = UserDefaults.standard()
    totalCoins = totalCoinDefault.integer(forKey: "Totalcoin")
    totalCoinLabel.text = "\(self.totalCoins)"

    func currencyUpdate(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval){

        if ( coin > 0) {

            totalCoins += self.coin
            totalCoinLabel.text = NSString(format: "Totalcoin : %i", totalCoins) as String

            let totalcoinDefault = UserDefaults.standard()
            totalcoinDefault.setValue(totalCoins, forKey: "Totalcoin")
            totalcoinDefault.synchronize()

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
let totalCoinDefault = UserDefaults.standard()
totalCoins = totalCoinDefault.integer(forKey: "Totalcoin")
totalCoinLabel.text = "\(self.totalCoins)"

if ( coin > 0) {
    totalCoins += self.coin
    totalCoinLabel.text = String(format: "Totalcoin : %i",totalCoins)
    totalcoinDefault.setValue(totalCoins, forKey: "Totalcoin")
    totalcoinDefault.synchronize()
}
```

You don't need this func.

Comment: Swift native type is String, not NSString. Btw String also has all NSString methods so you dont need to go all the way around. No need to force synchronization. You should use set(value:) Swift 3

Comment: I just copy his code and removed the func. I will edit it now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however removing the function did not change the overall output.

Comment: I guess it's because you have totalCoins and self.toalCoins. I don't have the whole code to be sure with the answer.